# Providing Select2 data after AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I'm trying to provide data to a `Select2` dropdown after a `AJAX` call. However, it seems that the dropdown is not getting any data even though the `AJAX` call works perfectly and returns the expected results. Here is the code. Note that the dropdown is inside a `JQuery UI` modal called `#dialog-create-circle` and that the `Select2` element is only created when the modal is opened by clicking the button `#createCircle`. I observed that even if I open the modal after allowing sufficient time for the `AJAX` call to finish, still the data is not being loaded to the `Select2` dropdown. I'd really appreciate some help on this.

```
var availableTags=[];

$.ajax({
    'url': '{{site.uri.public}}/getUserList', 
    'type': 'GET', 
    'dataType': 'json', 
    'data': {}, 
    'success': function(data) {
        availableTags=data;                 
    },
    'error': function(data) {  
    }
});

$( "#createCircle" ).click(function() {

      $( "#dialog-create-circle").dialog( "open" );


      $("#dropdown").select2({
        data: availableTags
      });

});
```

Comment: Whats is returned in data? Why `data` as you send is empty {}?

Comment: Try a `console.log(data)` in the success callback.

Comment: If the availableTags is not empty, try alter to `data: this.availableTags`. In worst of options, you can call the ajax inside click event, and set dropdown data at success.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @Lucas Costa, wrap ajax in a function and call when needed is one option. This way you can also pass anything in like other elements or urls etc:

```
function fillSelect2(){
  $.ajax({
    'url': '{{site.uri.public}}/getUserList', 
    'type': 'GET', 
    'dataType': 'json', 
    'data': {}, 
    'success': function(data) {
        $("#dropdown").select2({
          data: data
        });
    },
    'error': function(data) {  
    }
  });
});

$( "#createCircle" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog-create-circle").dialog( "open" ); 
  fillSelect2(); /* dialog now open, $('#dropdown') should be good to fill */
});
```